# Something like SQL "LIKE" but in PHP

Tags: php

I have few url in my database, it goes like:

id  url

```
1 http://test.com/embed-990.html
2. http://test2.com/embed-011.html
3. http://test3.com/embed-022.html
```

How I could make a simple php code if one of url doesn't exist in database, just to load another? I need to check these url by domain as well.

For example something like this:

```
if($data['url'] == "test.com") {
 echo "my embed code number 1";
} elseif($data['url'] == "test2.com") {
 echo "my another embed code";
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [parse the URL](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) to get the host then compare it.

```
$dataurl = array('http://test.com/embed-990.html', 
                 'http://test2.com/embed-011.html',
                 'http://test3.com/embed-022.html');
foreach($dataurl as $url) {
    switch(parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST)) {
        case 'test.com':
            echo 'test domain';
        break;
        case 'test2.com':
            echo 'test domain 2';
        break;
        default:
            echo 'unknown';
        break;
    }
    echo $url . PHP_EOL;
}
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/nmukK

For the question `Something like SQL “LIKE”` you could use a regex in `preg_match`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `substr_count`

```
if (substr_count($data['url'], 'test.com') > 0) {
    echo "my embed code number 1";
}
else if (substr_count($data['url'], 'test2.com') > 0) {
    echo "my embed code number 2";
}
```

or `strpos`

```
if (strpos($data['url'],'test.com') !== false) {
    echo "my embed code number 1";
}
else if (strpos($data['url'],'test2.com') !== false) {
    echo "my embed code number 2";
}
```

or `preg_match`

```
if(preg_match('/test.com/',$data['url']))
{
    echo "my embed code number 1";
}
else if(preg_match('/test2.com/',$data['url']))
{
    echo "my embed code number 2";
}
```

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of the exact match ( you could do `==` with less overhead ), and your syntax is wrong because you need to escape the `.` in the Regx or it will match any character at that position, for example `/test2.com/` matches `test2-com/` see: https://regex101.com/r/snuqRc/2

Comment: Yes you are right but there I try to suggest the functions which could be use as this point.

Comment: and for exact match in regex should be use only test1 or test2 but I think this not a actual text to check there.

Comment: Yes but, logically these are equivalent `if(preg_match('/test\.com/',$data['url']))` and `if( 'test.com' == $data['url])` which fails to show the "power" of pattern matching.  I guess "technically" you could argue that this `/^test\.com$/` would be equivalent  because yours will match `sometest.com`, but that's not clear in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regx

```
$domains = ['test.com', 'test1.com', 'test20.com'];
foreach( $domains as $domain ){
    if(preg_match('/test([0-9]*)\.com/', $domain, $match)){
        echo "my embed code number {$match[1]}\n";
    }
}
```

Outputs:

```
my embed code number 
my embed code number 1
my embed code number 20
```

you can test it here

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1d4ed1d7505a43b5a06b5ef6ef83468b20b47799

For the regx

- `test` matches `test` literally
- `([0-9]*)` - capture group, matches `0-9` none or more times
- `\.` matches `.` literally
- `com` matches `com` literally

One thing to note is that placing the `*` outside the capture group `([0-9])*` will match and pass the if, but will not capture anything within the capture group.  This makes sense, but its important to note because you'll get this message:

> **Notice**:  Undefined offset: 1 in **[...][...]** on line **6**

for `test.com`.

If you want to match the number in `embed-`  You can use one of these

```
     '/test\.com\/embed-([0-9]{3})\.html/'
     '/\/embed-([0-9]{3})\.html/'
     '/\/embed-([0-9]{3})\./'
```

Depending how specific you want to be.  You can play around with different Regx on this page.

https://regex101.com/r/snuqRc/1

Regular expressions are very powerful, they are meant for pattern matching, which is what you need.

Cheers.